# HTTP Libraries in elixir

Tags: erlang, elixir

This question is more of getting information about different HTTP Libraries in elixir.

I have been using HTTPoison for a long time in my all elixir projects. which is a wrapper around Hackney. I read some stuff on http://big-elephants.com/2019-05/gun/ about hackney as

> Occasionally hackney could get stuck, so all the calls to HTTPoison
>   would be hanging and blocking caller processes.

Let me ask with an example, I was using Poison in my project and I considered it to be a best JSON Parser, then I saw Jason.

> The primary reason is performance. Jason is about twice as fast and
>   uses half the memory while being almost 100% functionally compatible
>   with Poison (it covers all the features used directly in Phoenix).

I know the reason why I want to switch to Jason instead of Poison.

In HTTP, I can see there are Tesla, Mint and Gun. I just want to know the perspective of switching from something Famous to I may say Accurate one?

Comment: I am not sure about `Tesla` but I believe that `Mint` and `Gun` are a bit too low level and you'd probably have to build on top of them to be able to use them comfortably, so I guess it's a trade off between control and speed of development.

Comment: I'm more familiar with HTTPoison, but Tesla looks pretty sweet, and I've wanted to build something with it (haven't yet). One of the big draws for me is it lets you swap out HTTP implementations, so if you decide you don't like hackney you can go with something else under the hood.

Comment: I've been using Tesla for a while and I've been pleased with it. Using plug/middleware to build client libraries is clean and straight-forward. And with Tesla, you can configure the adapter to be whatever you want and it comes with out-of-the-box support for hackney, ibrowse, httpc, mint, and gun.

Comment: I use Jason as my JSON parser. Then if I need to call an external API or something then I use Tesla....but it still uses Jason to parse the JSON based on my setup. Jason is just a JSON parser. If you need call an external API or something, then use Tesla.